# How to serve a CSS file from Google Apps Script

Tags: css, google-apps-script

**Is it possible to serve a CSS file from Apps Script to a web page via @import and, if so, how?**

Here is what I have in my Apps Script project:

```
function doGet() {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("#topbar {display: none;}").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

And here is what I have on my web page:

```
<style>
    @import url("//script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzQ6UcF-f8RdARqSmLLnIztDUF-TocDcc2ZWKnXLDZfZKImcrD1/exec");
</style>
```

The script is published and can be accessed anonymously. It does in fact serve the text when viewed in the browser.

However, the styles on the page do not appear to take effect, nor are they even registered upon the elements which they target (`#topbar`), as verified using dev. tools/inspector. In other words, it's not a case of being overridden by another rule.

Chrome displays the following notice in console:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "https://script.googleusercontent.com/a/macros/xxxxxxxxx.com/echo?user_content_key=EwpjT6XHtgCE9TjjZiVvMu_D8SAtW6MRfu_EAMLFwMsGtfIOxw0i_lZeakV7d_fVAoQhFdRzoggswuridc7V9N-e1iQg-Agnm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_nRPgeZU6HP-ROivF5cq8Yy1TNiq6oZe8h0lmODcuY_1nzLek9VwvQZkF54xdAL-niFUG-amClvBrAUVm6NjncJhe06LYrp7Rujisx4EZAUceDIgHEbXEHQ&lib=Mp-3UT9miDqSgBd2rh0D-kk71SnnNhlD3".
```

Note that:

1. Apps Script is limited in the MIME types it allows, and I don't believe 'text/css' is one of them
2. Chrome does still seem to know to interpret it as a CSS file, so I don't think MIME type is the problem.
3. I must use `@import` due to client-side restrictions for the project.
4. I [noticed here](http://googleappscripting.com/doget-dopost-tutorial-examples/) that returning a blob offers additional MIME types, but I'm unsure if that's an applicable path to solving this problem.

Comment: What language is using `@import` ?  You should include that in the tags.  CSS in a style tag only takes affect if it is present when the web page first loads.  You can't load CSS after the page has loaded and have it take affect.  Try putting a `<link>` tag in your html header instead:  `<link href="//script.google.com/macros/s" rel="stylesheet">`  The `href` attribute of a link tag makes a GET request to the URL.  I have not tried this, and I don't really know what I'm talking about on this issue, but that's what I'd try.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the CSS @import directive allowed to use non-static files. What is the output in the 'Sources' tab of Chrome Developer Tools? Does the remote script actually return any content?

Comment: Sandy: Regarding "...only takes affect if it is present when the web page first loads." - Thanks, that could be part of the problem. I did not know that, as I've never used @import before (always used <link> as you suggested). Unfortunately, that wasn't an option in this case.

Anton: You might be right. I couldn't find anything definitive on that, and can't test it myself. That could also be part of the problem though.

In light of these potential problems, I solved it by hosting a CSS file in drive, obtaining the direct link, and using "Drive Notepad" to edit the file in the future.